# Ruby on Rails using Apache 2 with passanger "mod_rails" kind of working but not really

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger

Alright I'll try and make this as short as possible.  Currently I'm running OS X (10.8.4) with the default Apache 2 install.  I installed passenger using home brew.  I went through the setup wizard, and mod_rails appears to be working because I see this log statement, `[ 2013-09-03 01:33:21.3513 34289/0x7fff71bf9180 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:642 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!` in the `/var/log/apache2/error_log` file.

When I navigate to *localhost* in a web browser I get the following, however the `rails.png` file isn't showing.

The `access_log` for Apache 2 looks like the following,

http://pastie.org/8293413#

The `httpd.conf` file,

```
# Added by Chris - 27AUG13
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/capin/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.14/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Users/capin/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.14
PassengerDefaultRuby /Users/capin/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName lucky
    # Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/simple_cms/public 
      <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/simple_cms/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So for whatever reason the rails.png file isn't loading :/

[image]

Comment: did you complied your assets and also check your `Capfile`
does it contain `load 'deploy/assets'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out why the rails.png file wasn't loading.  It was because the rails application was trying to connect to a database, and I had not created the database in MySQL.  I was getting the following error in my Apache error log file, `error_log`

http://pastie.org/8295425

So I created the MySQL database according to what was specified in the `database.yml` and then I reloaded the `localhost` page, and whala,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're looking at a static file, public/index.html. Phusion Passenger's **static asset acceleration** feature makes Apache serve that file instead of Rails, so the request never reaches Rails.

Comment: how would I make that request reach rails?